# Using Ola Hallengren's backup solution - Can't exclude databases

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-agent, ola-hallengren

I am using the newest version of Ola's scripts.  When backing-up databases, I'm experiencing an issue with excluding certain databases.
The [website](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) states, if you want to backup all User database except X use the following for @Databases:

```
USER_DATABASES, -Db1
```

So, I'm running the following:

```
EXECUTE Maintdb.[dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES,-AdventureWorks2014 -Sandbox',
@Directory = 'G:\Bckps',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Verify = 'Y',
@CleanupTime = '36',
@CleanupMode = 'AFTER_BACKUP',
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@LogToTable = 'Y'
```

The issue is, all User databases get backed-up.  Output is:

```
The following databases in the @Databases parameter do not exist: [AdventureWorks2014 -Sandbox].
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after AdventureWorks2014 - it is a comma separated list you are supplying in the @Databases string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @LowlyDBA noted, your `@Databases` parameter is incorrect. It's a CSV list of database names (or database name patterns) and you've omitted a necessary comma.

It should be:

`@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES,-AdventureWorks2014, -Sandbox'`