# Best Practice for full backup and transaction log truncation

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am new to SQL Server DB. Could someone please let me know what would be the best practice to do a full backup and truncate the transaction log.

If you could please let me know the strategy you are using in your company, that would give me some idea and help me learn from the documentation. I would also like to know if there is any white paper or article that explains with examples.

Comment: This depends on your RPO (Recovery Point Objective). Do you need point-in-time recovery? How much time of data loss is acceptable to you?...e.g. 1 minute, 5 minutes, 15 minutes, 1 hour, etc? How big is the database?

Comment: A fairly standard backup cycle on many servers is: full daily, diff 4-6 per day and logs every few minutes

Answer (score 1):

there is a good starting point that is a very popular thing among DBAs which is [Ola Hallengren's backup solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/266037/22336)

Google it, download and install it, and read about it.

it is all dependable on your circumstances.

let's say you have a development environment, you want to test things - because this is exactly what you need to learn more.

I would schedule the full backup to 6Pm, the diff backup to 12AM and take transaction logs every 20 min.

things that you need to do are also, [restore verify only](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190542/22336), or just restore a backup to a different location to check if all is ok.

another thing - if you plan to do something and break the database, take a full backup (or diff) [with copy_only](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/45876/22336) that way you dont upset the log chain.